# What are some ways to figure out related products/questions/items anything?

Tags: node.js, algorithm, machine-learning

What are some ways including machine learning that I can use in my projects to generate things related to another. Like related apps, related websites, related products, etc.

I've been brainstorming these are strategies...

one way i can think of is show items from same category. But that would be too broad.

2nd way improves upon previous step, it's to keep track of what people click next and promote that item. Meanwhile keep bottom list randomized to let other relevant items show up and get clicked.

3rd way is to use machine learning and provide training data somehow and use that.

I want something simple but smart, as it gets better with time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Collaborative filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering) is designed for solving exactly this problem. The problem with this approach is that produces good results having a lot of data only. I mean... **A LOT**. And it's not a really simple thing to use. However, any machine learning technique is not simple. There are some node.js packages for CF available, but I have no idea how good are they.

Comment: wow that wikipedia has whole section on right on different recommendation systems